# Property 'get' does not exist on type 'Cache'. NestJs project

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, redis, nestjs

I'm trying to set up `Redis caching` for my `nestjs`-`graphql` project by following this [official guide](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching) and this [tutorial](https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2020/12/nestjs-redis-cache.html). I'm following the exact steps that are mentioned but I'm getting this error that `Property 'get' does not exist on type 'Cache'.`

Here's the exact code

```
import {User} from './user.entity'
import {Resolver, Query, ResolveField, Args, Parent, Mutation} from '@nestjs/graphql'
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { PostsService } from '../posts/posts.service';
import { CurrentUser } from 'src/auth/auth.resolver';
import { CACHE_MANAGER, Inject, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GqlAuthGuard } from 'src/auth/graphql-auth.guard';
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager'; <---------this is you need to import
@Resolver(of => User)
export class UsersResolver {
  constructor(
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache,
    private usersService: UsersService,
    private postsService: PostsService,
  ) {}

  @Query()
  async getUsers() {
    const value = await this.cacheManager.get('key'); //Now .get property is working.
    if(value){                                       
      console.log({                                  
        data: value,                                 
        loadsFrom: 'redis cache'
      })
    }
    return await this.usersService.findAll();
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding the import for Cache as suggested by @ArekRGW. `import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';`

Answer (score 21):

Import the `Cache` used in

`@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache`

from `cache-manager`

import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much code but one thing that comes to my mind is that Nest couldn't resolve the dependency or it resolved it wrongly. I don't see any import of type `Cache` look at the docs you have provided (quote below) maybe it will help.

> The Cache class is imported from the cache-manager, while CACHE_MANAGER token from the @nestjs/common package.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Snehasish Dawn, I would upvote your answer if I could...
`Cache` is a default interface of typescript so it is not imported from `cache-manager` by default by the IDE.
([link to typescript documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.cache.html))

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33135845)

Comment: It provides an answer to the error `Property 'get' does not exist on type 'Cache'` as @Snehasish Dawn gave the solution without explaining why...
I am sorry if that was not the right place to put a comment...